# Folder cannot be shared because of missing packages - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, samba, shared-folders, sharing

I want to share my Public folder on Ubuntu 16.04, but in preferences I see that *This feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system*.
[Screenshot of preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh6aK.jpg)

**samba** & **system-config-samba** are already installed on my PC.
What exactly packages do I need to install?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `apache` installed?

Comment: @George No, I don't. I'll try to check this idea.